# Access System Collection list within a listview phone 8.1 none silverlight

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to access the contents of a list with a list specifcally show_times now I have got this far that is displaying below the cinema name which is what I want but its just showing the System.Collection Variable and not the data.

```
private async void listViewShowtimes_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        popcornpk_Dal _dal = new popcornpk_Dal();
        MovieDetail _showTimes = await _dal.GetMovieShowtimesAsync();
        var listView = (ListView)sender;
        listView.ItemsSource = _showTimes.fetch_timing.ToList();     


}
```

Now what i Need is the list to be appearing below the cinema name which i thought the following would do this but it has not

```
<Pivot x:Name="myPivot">
        <PivotItem x:Name="pvtMoveDetails" Header="movie details" Margin="28,0,10,22.5" >
            <StackPanel Height="505">

                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition  />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image x:Name="moveImage"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Source="{Binding image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="186"    Width="112"/>


                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="txtTtile" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29"  Text="txttitle"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Description"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  FontSize="13" x:Name="txtPlot" Text="{Binding Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371" Foreground="White" Height="247"  />



                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </PivotItem>


        <PivotItem x:Name="pvtShowTimes" Header="showtimes">


                <ListView x:Name="listViewShowtimes" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Loaded="listViewShowtimes_Loaded">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition  />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock FontSize="13"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="txtshowtime"  Text="{Binding theater_name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" />
                            <TextBlock FontSize="13" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="txtshow_times"  Text="{Binding show_times}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" />


                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

        </PivotItem>
        <!-- Add more pivot items if your View calls for it -->
    </Pivot>
```

My GetShowTimesAsync Call is

```
public async Task<MovieDetail> GetMovieShowtimesAsync()
{
        string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "movie_details");
        var jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovieDetail>(jsonresult);


        return jarray;
}
```

Class is

```
    public class MovieDetails
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string secondry_images { get; set; }
        public string actor { get; set; }
        public string actoress { get; set; }
        public string director { get; set; }
        public string music_director { get; set; }
        public string release_date { get; set; }
        public string tags { get; set; }
        public string age_restriction { get; set; }
        public string box_office { get; set; }
        public string official_site { get; set; }
        public string duration { get; set; }
        public string writers { get; set; }
        public int imdb { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string created { get; set; }
        public string modified { get; set; }
        public string movie_category_id { get; set; }
        public string slug { get; set; }
        public string movie_show_time_id { get; set; }
        public string theatre_movie_screen_id { get; set; }
        public string videous { get; set; }
        public string videos { get; set; }
        public string comming_soon { get; set; }
        public int avg { get; set; }
        public string movie_details_url { get; set; }
    }

    public class FetchTiming
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string theater_name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public List<string> show_times { get; set; }
        public string screen_id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDetail
    {
        public MovieDetails movie_details { get; set; }
        public List<FetchTiming> fetch_timing { get; set; }
    }
```

What is Hapening though is the following 
[image]

Ideally what i want to be able to do is

Cinema Name 
  Film showing at : 9:30,10:30 etc 
Then Nxt Cinema
  Next Showtimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't display a list directly in a text control. Depending on your needs, you have two solutions:

1. If you want to display your times on the same line, the easiest solution is to add a property on your class and join the strings there:

   ```
   public class FetchTiming
   {
       public List<string> show_times { get; set; }
       public string FormattedShowTimes 
       {
           get
           {
               return string.Join(", ", this.show_times);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   (then you bind `FormattedShowTimes` instead of `show_times`)
2. If you want to display your times on separate lines, then you should use an `ItemsControl` :

   ```
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=show_times}">
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
           </DataTemplate>
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
   ```

   Of course, you can customize the datatemplate to fit your needs.

Comment: thanks ill give that shot anyreason why my @ comment facility not working yet here btw, Is their anyway of getting the show time to appear on top of a graphic at all ? like a ticket graphic

Comment: that worked but what should my bidning path be for itemsource when i want to show FormattedShowTimes ? as i tried   <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FormattedShowTimes}"> and it didnt work

Comment: @windowsphoneexpertuk You should use either of the solutions, not both. `ItemsSource` expects a collection, so you can't bind it to `FormattedShowTimes`, only to `show_times`.

Comment: but then how does Formatted show times then get shown on screen ?

Comment: @windowsphoneexpertuk  `FormattedShowTimes` is only if you keep on using the TextBlock. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormattedShowTimes}" />`

Comment: ahy ok sorry my confusion with the itemscontrol i got it sorted by the way do you no how i can put an image behind the text using items control he wants an image of a movie ticket behind it ?.